# Static function to return constant float

Tags: c++

I've got a class, call it myClass which has pi stored as a const float like so:

```
const float pi = 3.1415;
```

and a public function to return its value:

```
static float _pi() { return pi; };
```

when I want to use this pi number in my other code by calling it like this:

```
myClass::_pi
```

I get this error which I don't really understand, why shouldn't I be able to return a value like this? and how can I make it work as intended?

```
expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type
```

Comment: `float x = myClass::_pi();`

Comment: Note for your next question: posting half a line here and there is useless, you need to post reasonably complete (that doesn't mean long) examples.

Comment: okay, that's embarrasing.. and here I've been searching everywhere for a solution to something that seems to work.. and it's just me being stupid and forgetting the (), thanks for spotting that for me, guess I'm tired..

Comment: Note that the literal `3.1415` isn't a `float` -- it's a `double`.  To specify a `float` literal append the `f` suffix, as with `3.1415f`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I only post what small portion of the code that could potentially be the problem

Comment: @Jacco Your need to ask proves that you are not qualified to decide where the problem lies. This is not to be rude, it is to help you get better answers to your questions.

Comment: Side note: avoid leading underscores (even legal in some situations)

Comment: @MarcGlisse I appreciate that, but I still don't see what else I would have to provide in this case to solve the problem.

Comment: @Jacco You could have provided the complete line where you used _pi, so it is clear if you are missing () or not. The point is that you should first minimize your example (hopefully you will notice the error yourself in the process) and then post the entire thing, so you don't have to be lucky to pick the right pieces.

Answer (score 1):

First, a static member function cannot access a non-static member variable without an instance of the class.

```
const float pi = 3.1415;           // Non-static. Created upon instantiation
static float _pi() { return pi; }; // Error. No access to instance.
```

If you want to statically call the function `_pi` then you should also make the constant `pi` static.

Secondly, when calling the function `pi` you must call it with `()`, e.g.

```
float x = myClass::_pi();
```

Finally you could use C++11 `constexpr` to make `pi` and the return value of `_pi` compile time constants. This will cause the compiler to insert the constant at compile time at every call site. Also you can use the expression `_pi()` in static asserts etc.

```
static constexpr float pi = 3.1415f;       // Use 'f' postfix for float literals.
static constexpr float _pi() { return pi; }
```

Works:

```
static_assert(myClass::_pi() == 3.1415f, "Uh-oh, wrong value.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just spitballing but people have a tendency to const float pi or kPI or whatever notation you like in a basic math header instead of this. Is pi gonna be different anywhere else?